# Browser detect downloads

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, download, visual-studio-2012

I am a VB.NET programmer and am wanting to make a simple application that will load when a download link is clicked in a browser. I am also wanting to filename of the download link.

I know applications like GetRight and other software do this.

How is the best way to do this? Is there some simple source code that I can have a look at to start on this?

thanks

Comment: Technically, EVERYTHING a browser fetches is a download. I'm guessing you want to intercept zip/avi/wmv/rar/etc... type files?

Comment: @SLacks: Potentially for all browsers, but I am wanting to create it for Google Chrome at the moment.

Comment: @Marc B: I am after the filename. From that I can easily get the filename type.

Comment: @DarrylJanecek, No, you cannot get the file type from a file name.  This is especially true on resources coming from web servers.